# Testng test suite order of test class execution

Tags: testng

I found a set of test classes which uses testng framework which does not define a testng.xml. Thus, it does not define the preserver-order attribute. 
These tests have to be executed in a particular order in this case in order to avoid failure. They seem to pass fine in my machine while it fails in some others.

What order does it use to execute tests in testng if the suite XML file is not defined and does it vary based on various factors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use order features like `dependsOn*`, `priority`, ... The order of tests is not specified and may depend on your system (jdk version for example).

Comment: Hi Julien, this is true in the case of test cases or to be clear - test methods we write. But I am referring to test classes, we can control the order of test class execution using a test suite XML, but without that file how does the order of test classes stack up?

Comment: As I said, it is not specified by the documentation, it can change and it depends on the runner implementation you use (eclipse, intellij, gradle, maven, ant, ...).

Comment: Okay, I do get it.

Comment: But if you really need a specific order, you can implement your own logic too with http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors